# How to run our Android App from Eclipse to Android Phone (Device)..?

Tags: android

need Help..!

I,m trying to run my Android App from Eclipse to Android phone ( Samsung Galaxy-Y-DUOS ) , For that I followed the following steps---

1. Installed Samsung Kies.
2. settings->applications->Unknown Sources, check it true
3. settings->applications->Development->USB Debugging, check it true

But still when I start running my Application, It gets run on Emulator, And I'm unable to find the problem.

Comment: go to device manager of computer and check if it recognise your hardware.. if it is signed with yello ! mark then problem with the driver

Comment: Did u install the samsung usb driver?

Comment: @ Imran Yes I have Installed the USB driver.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on `project -> Run As -> Run Configuration`.
Here there are 3 tabs

2nd one is `Target`. Select : `Always prompt to pick device`.
Now run your project and check if your mobile device is detected i.e `USB driver` are installed. If yes the click on it and Click `Run button`.

Comment: @Sandy I did what You told and run my project, but whet the Android Device Chooser Window appears It seems there is no running device (Running Android Device List is blank).

Comment: Ok it means that USB driver are not installed. You need to install it first.

Comment: Do one thing download PDAnet and install on your machin and then try: you can downlaod it from here http://pdanet.co/a/

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project, select Run As > Run Configurations and select "Manually choose".

If this does not work open a shell and type "adb devices" and see if your device is there.

Comment: @ Soham i have tried this But when I type "adb devices" this command, It gives me the following error--   "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @user1926512 did you go to the platform tools in your command prompt. you need to go the path of the platform-tools in android sdk . you will have adb there. you can execute the command then

Comment: Simple things first. @user1926512 where is your Android SDK located? That is, where did you download and extract the Android SDK ZIP file?

Comment: No, I asked you this - where is it located?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury This is my SDK Path=> E:\Dnyanesh\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk

Comment: Then, open Command Prompt and type ``cd E:\Dnyanesh\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools\`` and _then_ type `adb devices`.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I did that but "List of devices attached" is Blank, i.e. It seems there is no device attached..

Comment: Hm. That means that your PC can't see the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

Connect your phone to computer via USB
Enable USB debugging on your phone: Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB debugging
Change Run configuration in your Eclipse project: right click -> Run As -> Run Configurations. In the Target tab choose Always prompt to pick device (or Manual). Then Apply, Run.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all enable USB DEBUGGING MODE in your android device.
2. After that connect your android device to your computer or wherever you installed android studio.
3. Then run your project, at that time you see a dialog box pops and ask whether you wanna run android virtual device or your real device (It should show online).
4. Then select your device and finally your app is installed on your device and it is running.