# how to run eclipse project on galaxy trend plus gt s 7580

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, mobile, configuration

I've tried  [Why doesn't Eclipse see my Samsung Galaxy phone even though I can transfer files using a drive letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908301/why-doesnt-eclipse-see-my-samsung-galaxy-phone-even-though-i-can-transfer-files)
and [How to run our Android App from Eclipse to Android Phone (Device)..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728125/how-to-run-our-android-app-from-eclipse-to-android-phone-device)
and a lot of googling but couldn't find the required solution. I even did not find the developers option in settings of galaxy trend plus gt s7580. please help me. I wanted to run the eclipse projects on which I m programing.please help me

Comment: do as JafarKhQ said and install `Kies` on your pc and check your device is present in myComputer(DEVICEMANAGER) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable developer options on android 4.2+

1- Open Settings.
2- Go to About device.
3- Tap on Build number 7 times.
4- Go back to Setting, you can see Developer options

Comment: Thnx alot. Thnx a loy bro